# CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699/InvalidClassException while accessing ejb bean with enum from swing after weblogic 12.2.1.3 upgrade

Tags: java, java-8, enums, ejb, weblogic12c

```
com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0 read_value
WARNING: "IOP00810211: (MARSHAL) Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream"
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)

**Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.xxxx.xxxx.VcrConfigRelationship$VcrConfigType; UnsupportedOperationException accessing no-arg constructor**
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1471)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:414)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:1020)

java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:227)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:95)

public class VcrConfigRelationship implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public enum VcrConfigType {
        TEST("TEST"), TESTENV("TESTENV"),NULL;
        private String value;
        private VcrConfigType() {
            this.value = null;
        }
        private VcrConfigType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
    private VcrConfigType configCd;
    public VcrConfigRelationship(int configParamId, VcrConfigType configCd) {
        super();
        this.configParamId = configParamId;
        this.configCd = configCd;
    }
```

***Application details-** swing,ejb,weglobic 12.2.1.3,java 8- client server desktop application

- Recently, we have upgraded our application from jdk 7 to 8 and weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.3. So, based on weblogic documentation, we have replaced wlfullclient.jar with wlthin3client.jar.
- However, after replacing this jar we are getting above exception in ew of the ejb classes communication from client. its not causing issue in all ejbs. but the serializable java bean having enum causing this issue. And, those classes and enum are tightly integrated in the application. So, cant change the implementation.

  -We have tried ordering different WL client jars like wlclient.jar,wlthin3client.jar,wljmsclient.jar and few others in client app classpath, but no success.
- If I use previous WL version wlfullclient.jar everything works fine. However, as per WL docs, that jar is deprecated and not availble in WL(12.2.1.3)and we need to replace it with wlthin3client.jar.*

Comment: …and does `com.xxxx.xxxx.VcrConfigRelationship$VcrConfigType` have an accessible no-arg constructor?

Comment: No. based on below statement==>An object is serializable (itself implements the Serializable interface) even if its superclass is not. However, the first superclass in the hierarchy of the serializable class, that does not implements Serializable interface, MUST have a no-arg constructor. If this is violated, readObject() will produce a java.io.InvalidClassException in runtime.   And, the above code exists since long before upgradation. So, why its work for wlfullclient.jar?

Comment: It’s not enough for the superclass to have a no-arg constructor, said constructor must also be accessible by the subclass (being `public` or `protected` or default when being in the same package). So you’re saying `VcrConfigType` is not serializable and you’re using a serializable subclass of it?

Comment: VcrConfigType is enum inside VcrConfigRelationship.java serializable bean. I have added sample code of this class above.

Comment: Then, the rule about superclass constructor accessibility does not apply, as `enum` constants are special. The standard serialization will just record type and name and acquire the actual constant from the type when deserializing. This doesn’t match with IIOP, however, regardless of what it does, it can not apply the standard object serialization procedure (which it seems to be trying in your case). `java.lang.Enum` doesn’t have a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the important info Holger. So, any other option to resolve this issue?

Comment: Depends on what the actual issue is. A simple work-around would be to give `VcrConfigRelationship` a `writeObject` method  writing `configCd.name()` and  a `readObject` method reading the string, followed by `configCd = VcrConfigType.valueOf(stringJustRead);`. Of course, that only works if there are not too many other use sites of `VcrConfigType`.

Comment: Its not helping :(  Still I am not able to figure out how enum is causing InvalidClassException after Weblogic upgrade? earlier it was working fine.